# Who is our Jon Skeet?

Tags: discussion

[Jon Skeet] is famous on Stack Overflow. Who is our Jon Skeet and associated facts. Propose one user per answer, and their awesome feats!

Also, humor should generally be related to world building, and this site's culture, of course.